# Read a big data file with headlines into a matrix

Tags: matlab, bigdata

I have a file that looks like this (with real data and much bigger):

```
A   B      C  D E  F G     H   I
1   105.28 1 22 84 2 10.55 21  2
2   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
3   150.23 3 78 22 0 12.02 11  0
4   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
5   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
6   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
...
17000 357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
```

I want to import all the numerical value into a matrix, skipping the headlines. For that purpose I use this code:

```
Filename = 'test.txt';
A = dlmread(Filename,' ',1,0); %Imports the whole data into a matrix
```

The problem with this is just that `A` is a `17 000 * 1` vector instead of a matrix with several columns. If I manual edit the data file, remove the headlines and just run this it works:

```
A = dlmread(Filename); %Imports the whole data into a matrix
```

But I would prefer not to do this since the headlines are used later on in the code. Any advice how to get this work?

edit: solved by using

```
'   '
```

instead of just

```
' '
```

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter is  ' ' and not a comma?

Comment: Yes, there are no commas in the file.

Comment: Try using a range instead maybe?
M = dlmread('filename', delimiter, range) -- range = [R1 C1 R2 C2]

Comment: The problem is that I have more than one data file and just want to skip the headline in it and then import the rest. I could do so, like I could edit the data file and remove the headline. But it would require a lot of extra work. If there is no other solution I will try your idea you.

Comment: Just tried it in R2016b. Worked fine. What are the contents of `A`?

Comment: It is:
`1   
105.28 
1 
22 
84 
2 
10.55 
21  
2
2
357.01
...`

I remember it worked fine for me in R2014, but not in R2017a for some reason.

Comment: You're right! It works, I just have to put in a bigger space! `'  '` instead of `' '`

Thanks a lot! You saved my sleep this night :)

Answer (score 0):

- Use the import tool.
- Make sure you choose the data.
- Generate script.